# The meaning of the answer to the disjunctive question

Tags: grammar, meaning

There's the question:"Nobody is getting a rise this year, are they?"
  If to answer "No, they aren't", it will mean that the salary of those people will remain the same.Everything is clear here.
  But if to answer "Yes, they are", what meaning will the sentence have?Will it mean that all those people will get a rise or will it mean that only some of them will get?

Comment: You would have to ask the person who made that reply which one they meant. It's impossible to tell from the words.

Comment: Agree.  The first person would follow with a clarification.   But would certainly not assume it was everyone.